# Padding в span

Tags: html, css

Вот проблема: http://jsfiddle.net/rVPwr/. Там для span задан padding 10px слева и справа. Он есть в начале и конце текста. Но вот между строк его нет. Возможно ли как то сделать отступы в промежуточных строках?

Comment: span имеет display: inline; это не прямоугольный  блок, сделайте display: block; или display: inline-block;

Answer (score 1):

Зачем такой большой кусок текста заключать в span?
Для этой цели есть замечательный элемент `<p></p>`

Ну а если Вам все-таки хочется использовать span, то внимательно прочитайте комментарий [[@eicto](/users/11304/eicto)](/users/11304/eicto) - он все правильно написал.

[Вот Вам для наглядности.](http://jsfiddle.net/Alex83/YnJxg/1/)

Если и это опять не то, то обратитесь к свойству line-height. Данной свойство задает межстрочный интервал.